# Canvas JS - X axis as Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, canvas

In Canvas JS i used chart from theme 2, i want to show the x axis as date string, not int.
Something like this:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(i.toString(),
            {
                animationEnabled: true,
                theme: "theme2",
                title:{
                    text: "Multi Series Spline Chart - Hide / Unhide via Legend"
                },
                axisY:[{
                  lineColor: "#4F81BC",
                  tickColor: "#4F81BC",
                  labelFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                  titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
                  lineThickness: 1000,
                },
                {
                  lineColor: "#C0504E",
                  tickColor: "#C0504E",
                  labelFontColor: "#C0504E",
                  titleFontColor: "#C0504E",
                  lineThickness: 1000,

                },
                {
                  lineColor: "#339933",
                  tickColor: "#339933",
                  labelFontColor: "#339933",
                  titleFontColor: "#339933",
                  lineThickness: 1000,
                },
                {
                  lineColor: "#6600cc",
                  tickColor: "#6600cc",
                  labelFontColor: "#6600cc",
                  titleFontColor: "#6600cc",
                  lineThickness: 1000,
                },
                {
                  lineColor: "#663300",
                  tickColor: "#663300",
                  labelFontColor: "#663300",
                  titleFontColor: "#663300",
                  lineThickness: 1000,
                }
                      ],
                data: [
                {
                    name: "1",
                    type: "spline", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                    showInLegend: true,        
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: '2016-03-04', y: 51 },
                        { x: '2016-03-05', y: 45}
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    name: "2",
                    type: "spline",
                    axisYIndex: 1,
                    showInLegend: true,            
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: '2016-03-04', y: 51 },
                        { x: '2016-03-05', y: 45}
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    name: "3",
                    type: "spline",
                    axisYIndex: 1,
                    showInLegend: true,            
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: '2016-03-04', y: 51 },
                        { x: '2016-03-05', y: 45}
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    name: "4",
                    type: "spline",
                    axisYIndex: 1,
                    showInLegend: true,            
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: '2016-03-04', y: 51 },
                        { x: '2016-03-05', y: 45}
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    name: "5",
                    type: "spline",
                    axisYIndex: 1,
                    showInLegend: true,            
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: '2016-03-04', y: 51 },
                        { x: '2016-03-05', y: 45}
                    ]
                    }
                ],
                legend: {
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    itemclick: function (e) {
                        if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                        } else {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                    }
                    chart.render();
                    }
                }
            });

            chart.render();
```

When i run this code, there isn't chart, but f i changed to int (1, 2, 3...) i will see the chart.

Any help guys?

Thanks

Comment: (place your mouse at `x=2016-03-05, y=45`) fatal error head exploded. you probably want something like a label instead. `dataPoints: [
    { label: "2016-03-05",  x: 10  }]`

Comment: @iHasCodeForU What about y axis? could you pass the code? thanks

Comment: the code i have posted would be wrong as noted on the website. `dataPoints: [
    { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
    { label: "orange", y: 15  },
    { label: "banana", y: 25  },
    { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
    { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
   ]` the labels would become the mark points for the x axis and the y axis would be the height.